# How to convert this sum into an equation?

Tags: summation

How to convert this sum into an equation?

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{C-1} i(R-i)(C-i) $$

Expanded:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{C-1} (RCi - Ri^2 -Ci^2 + i^3)  $$

Which can be represented as:

$$  RC\sum_{i=1}^{c-1}i - R\sum_{i=1}^{c-1}i^2-C\sum_{i=1}^{c-1}i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{c-1}i^3  $$

Using the Faulhaber formula and having n = c-1, it can be represented as:

$$ {1\over 2}RC(n^2+n) -{1\over6}R(2n^3+3n^2+n) - {1\over 6}C(2n^3+3n^2+n)+{1\over4}(n^4+2n^3+n^2)    $$

But the results from the sum and the formula from the Faulhaber formula are different. Where is my error?

Comment: You mean, simplify this ?

Comment: I don't see any error in what you did.  Maybe your sum is incorrect?

Comment: You are correct. There was an error in my sum. Marked your answer as correct since I wasn't sure it could be solved using Faulhaber's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the product, which will give terms in $i, i^2,$ and $i^3$.  Do you know how to sum each of those by [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)?

Comment: I tried using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html) but I don't get the same result.

Comment: The same result as what?  Yes, that is what you are looking for.  If we don't see your work we can't find the problem.

Comment: I just edited the question to add the procedure